# How to draw $\sin(x^2)$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, graphing-functions

I wonder if it is possible to draw **$\sin(x^2)$** by hand, I think it is impossible, but I'm not sure, it would be very useful if anyone can clarify if it is possible or not, and show what is the way to draw it if it is possible.

Thanks

Comment: Figure out where the zeroes and maxima and minima are by looking at where $x^2$ is a multiple of $\pi/2$. Then join those points by a smooth curve..

Comment: I’m in agreement with Ethan. If you think about maxima and minima carefully, you’ll find plotting the curve without the use of a computer or calculator not too terrible.

Comment: Some intuition: $\sin(x^2)$ is $\sin(|x|\cdot|x|)$, which can be thought of as a sinusoid with “frequency” $|x|$ (just as $\sin(kx)$ has frequency $k$). As $x$ gets further away from zero, then, the frequency of the sinusoid increases: the peaks cluster closer and closer together.

Answer (score 3):

it is an even function

$f(x) = \sin x^2\\
f(-x) = f(x)\\
f(0) = 0$

$f(x) > 0$ while $\sqrt \pi <x \sqrt \pi$

$f(x) = 0 $ when  $x = \pm \sqrt {n\pi}$

$f(x) = 1$ when $x = \pm \sqrt {\frac {2n+1\pi}{2}}$

$f(x) = -1$ when $x = \pm \sqrt {\frac {2n-1\pi}{2}}$

That give you plenty of points.

For most of the curve, it will resemble a standard sine wave, except the frequency increases as you move away from 0.

So something like:

[image]

Perhaps not incredibly precise, but it gives the idea.

Answer (score 1):

It is an even function whose roots occur at $\sqrt{\pi}\approx 1+\frac{3}{4}$, $\sqrt{2\pi}\approx 2+\frac{1}{2}$,$\sqrt{3\pi}\approx 3$,$\sqrt{4\pi}\approx 3+\frac{1}{2}$, $\sqrt{5\pi}\approx 4$. The first stationary point is located at $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}}\approx 1$, the behaviour in a right neighbourhood of the origin is the one of $x^2$ and it is an approximate sine function on the interval between two consecutive roots, so something like this:

[image]

Oh, no, the first stationary point is actually located at $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$, so something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did this with Python.

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
def sinsq(x):
    return math.sin(x*x)
x = [k/100 for k in range(1000)]
y = [sinsq(k) for k in x]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()`

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: That hardly answers the OP's question about drawing the graph "by hand".

Comment: OP needs to look at the maximima, minima and roots of the sine function and "connect the dots."

Comment: This shows the result is quite plottable.